# How to assign values to js variable from ajax function(PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax

```javascript
function loadCalender() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url()."catering"."/"."loadStoreCalender"; ?>',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      val: $(this).val()
    },
    context : this,
    success: function(result) {
      // I have to Assign value to Array in the following format
      //events[0] = { Title: "Booking Not Available", Date: new Date("05/13/2014") };
      //events[1] = { Title: "Booking Not Available", Date: new Date("04/21/2014") };
      //events[2] = { Title: "Booking Not Available", Date: new Date("04/22/2014") };
      //events[3] = { Title: "Booking Not Available", Date: new Date("04/23/2014") };
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

My Question is how could I pass the array value from PHP Controller to Ajax to achieve an array in the desire format (I mean

```
    //events[0] = { Title: "Booking Not Available", Date: new Date("05/13/2014") };
```

).

Below is my PHP Controller

```php
public function loadStoreCalender()
{
  $this->load->model('catering_model');
  $result=array();//???
  $storeId = $_POST['val'];
  $result = array("Title" => "Booking Not Available","Date" => new Date("04/21/2014")); // For Example
  die(json_encode($result));
}
```

I'm creating a function for Booking System with PHP CI and Ajax. I'm noob in working with array and ajax things. Please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're not returning a multidimensional array, you're just returning a single row. You probably need a loop in your controller to collect all the bookings into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadCalender(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."catering"."/"."loadStoreCalender"; ?>',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            val: $(this).val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        context : this,
        success: function(results) {
            callback(results);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Test
loadCalender(function(eventsJsonObjArray)
{
    console.log(eventsJsonObjArray);
});
```

Comment: Why the loop? Just do `events = result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadCalender(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."catering"."/"."loadStoreCalender"; ?>',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            val: $(this).val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        context : this,
        success: function(results) {
            callback(results);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Test
loadCalender(function(eventsJsonObjArray)
{
    console.log(eventsJsonObjArray);
});
```